# ParametricPlot3D: The Mesh shows some unexpected wires to the origin. How to remove them?

Tags: plotting

In the code below a hexagonal shape is defined and plotted. The ParametricPlot3D shows the hexagonal design almost as intended. However, the mesh makes some strange "wires" to x=y=0. This is unexpected as the function does not exist at these coordinates. Why am I seeing this strange behaviour at the center? How can the plot be improved?

I tried several things:
2nd plot: I also included these coordinates in the Exclusions in the second plot but this didn't help.

3th plot: When the mesh is not plotted the graph looks better, altough some polishing at the edges might improve the graph further.

4th plot. Other problems is encoutered in the 3Dplot.

```
 Remove["Global`*"];
 func[u0_, v0_] := Module[{u = u0, v = v0},
   {
    u, v,
    If[u == 0 && v == 0,
     Null,
     θ  = ArcTan[v, u];
     θN = Mod[θ, 3.1415/3., -3.1415/6.](*θ w.r.t North*);
     l  = Norm[{u, v}];
     vN = l*Cos[θN ];
     If[.3 < vN < .8, 2 - vN, Null] (*Make parabolic function(vN)*)
     ]
    }
   ]

 func[0., 0.]

 surfacePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[func[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> All]

 surfacePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[func[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Exclusions -> {u == 0, v == 0}, ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red}]

 surfacePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[func[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},(*Exclusions\[Rule]{{u\[Equal]0,
   u<.1}},*)PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None]

 surfacePlot = 
  Plot3D[func[u, v][[3]], {u, -1, 1.4}, {v, -1, 1.4}, PlotRange -> All,
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> { 30}]
```

[image: Plots of strange wires to u=v=x=y=0]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mapping is not continuous and the mesh just shows it.

```
fun1[u_, v_] := 2 - Norm[{u, v}]*Cos[Mod[ArcTan[v, u], Pi/3, -Pi/6]]
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, fun1[u, v]}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
                 RegionFunction -> (1.2 < fun1[#4, #5] < 1.7 &), PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your suggestion resulted in this improved figure with a more continuous mesh: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pIyKA.png. However, the edges are still not very sharp. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Is there another/better way to define the edge coordinates?

`fun1[u_, v_] := 2 - Norm[{u, v}]*Cos[Mod[ArcTan[v, u], Pi/3, -Pi/6]]; ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, fun1[u, v]}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
     RegionFunction -> (1.2 < fun1[#4, #5] < 1.7 &), PlotPoints -> 100, 
     MeshFunctions -> {ArcTan[#5, #4] &,
       (Sqrt[#4^2 + #5^2]*Cos[Mod[ArcTan[#5, #4], Pi/3, -Pi/6]] &)}
     ] `

Comment: @LvD I believe the better alternative is to draw six polygons instead of a Plot ...

Comment: Thanks @belisarius. 

I really need to use the defined function; a polygon is not a suited alternative. Actually, the function I want to plot is more complicated that the planes as I posted here. By using the `RegionFunction` and a high number of plotpoints I got the following result: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/3YmgL.png

Comment: @LvD Well, yes.Increasing PlotPoints and MaxRecursion you can always try to fill the gaps if you don't zoom too much. Thanks for the accept!