# Regular Polyhedra coordinate points generation

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Is it possible to get all points on a Polyhedron surface using two surface parameters, say

$ \phi,\theta $ spherical co-ordinates?

Just like in `ParametricPlot3D`, can we start with `PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron"]` to obtain spatial point positions?. The tip of position vector should cross edges automatically during $\phi,\theta$ sweep.

Comment: You can always make [this kind of tricks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69369/193)

Comment: @belisarius: fine,but want to append or prepend available Polyhedra.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69804/2731) is a nice start.

Comment: Stick a small sphere around the barycenter. Now parametrize by the spherical angles, using intersection of ray through spherical point (theta,phi) with polyhedron.

Comment: Clear enough, we need to have *direct* coordinates as function of ($\theta,\phi, n $).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Exploit the fact that the vertices of the dual to a Platonic solid correspond to the centers of the faces of the solid itself.  For instance, the dual to a cube is a regular octahedron, and the six vertices of this octahedron are in the directions of the centers of the faces of its dual cube.

Find the normalized directions of the face centers of the cube (for instance) this way:

```
FaceCenters = Normalize /@ PolyhedronData[PolyhedronData["Cube", "Dual"], "Faces"][[1]];
```

The `{x,y,z}` direction in Euclidean coordinates as a function of spherical angles θ and φ are of course:

```
x[θ_Real, φ_Real] := {Sin[θ] Cos[φ], 
                      Sin[θ] Sin[φ], 
                      Cos[θ]}
```

Now sweep through all spherical angles, and for each corresponding direction find the nearest face center direction (i.e., the one with the smallest angle to the direction defined by θ and φ).  For each such direction, the distance to the surface is 1/Sin[ψ], where ψ is the scalar angle between the candidate direction and its nearest face direction:

```
    SphericalPlot3D[
         1/Sin[x[θ, φ].Nearest[FaceCenters, x[θ, φ]][[1]]], 
         {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
         PlotPoints -> 100] // Quiet
```

[image: Cube fig]

If you repeat with a Tetrahedron, for instance, you get this:

[image: Tetrahedron fig]

If you repeat for an Octahedron, you get this:

[image: Octahedron fig]

If you repeat for a Dodecahedron, you get this:

[image: Dodecahdrond fig]

Comment: Wow... I really thought @Narasimhan would have accepted this answer!  What more can he possibly want?!

Comment: That was great. My apologies for  the inordinate delay earlier

Comment: Wow... two months late!  Better late than never!

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot3D[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Region"], 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]], 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Arg[x + I*y]]}, Mesh -> 20, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Region"], 
 MeshFunctions -> (Function[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ 
    ToSphericalCoordinates[{x, y, z}][[2 ;; 3]]), Mesh -> 20]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
regularPolyhedraParametricEquation[poly_String]:=
With[{sp={Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}},
 sp/Max[(Cross[#2-#1,#3-#1]&@@@PolyhedronData[poly,"Polygons"][[All,1]]).sp]];

regularPolyhedraList = PolyhedronData["Platonic"]
paraEqn = regularPolyhedraParametricEquation /@ regularPolyhedraList;

ParametricPlot3D[#,{θ,0,Pi},{ϕ,0,2Pi},Exclusions->None,PlotPoints->120,
  PlotStyle->Opacity[0.7]]&/@N[paraEqn]
```

> {Tetrahedron, Cube, Octahedron, Dodecahedron, Icosahedron}
> [image]

Related [Transform sphere into a cube](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174847/transform-sphere-into-a-cube)
[image]