# Transform sphere into a cube

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, animation

I'm trying to get into animation using Mathematica, and I want to create a simple animation where a sphere in a black space gets "morphed" into a cube. I know how to generate a cube and how to generate a sphere using Graphics3D:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[]]
Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]
```

But I'm not sure how to generate a "movie" of one morphing into another.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Slow, but it works:

```
Animate[
 RegionPlot3D[
  With[{u = Sin[t]^2*10 + 2}, 
   Abs[x]^u + Abs[y]^u + Abs[z]^u < 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, -1, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you got the formula?

Comment: @TreFox It's [a fairly well-known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#Unit_balls_in_normed_vector_spaces) in higher math.

Answer (score 17):

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
DynamicModule[{pts = MeshCoordinates[reg], 
  norms = Norm /@ MeshCoordinates[reg]}
 , Animate[
  Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[
    Dynamic[ pts  /(1 - t + t  norms) ],
    {EdgeForm@None, MeshCells[reg, {2}]}
    ]
  , {t, 0, 1}, AnimationRate -> 1, 
  AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a short explanation of how you put this code together?

Comment: @TreFox cuboid -> cuboid's mesh -> coordinates + polygons. Then, normalized coordinates of this cuboid are on a sphere so I just scale the norm between 1 and original one. I'm encouraging your to take this code apart and experiment, see what's inside.

Answer (score 7):

**Updated**

```
plt=ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi},
   PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, 
  Axes -> False, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#5, 1, 1, 0.75] &)];

cf = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, t}, (1 - t) v + t v/(Sqrt[2] Max[Abs[v]]),
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

Manipulate[plt /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[cf[pts, t], rest], {t, 0., 1}]
```

[image]

**Previous answer:**

Rectangle to circle:

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[(1 - t) (Max@Abs@{x, y} - 1) + t (x^2 + y^2 - 1) == 0,
  {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 80], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Cube to sphere:

```
frames = ParallelTable[
    ContourPlot3D[(1 - t) (Max[Abs@{x, y, z}] - 1) + t (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1) == 0,
     {x, -#, #}, {y, -#, #}, {z, -#, #}, 
       PlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] &@1.1,
         {t, 0, 1, 1/50.}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Animate[frames[[i]], {i, 1, Length[frames], 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: what a beautiful answer!

Comment: @BlackMild Thanks for your appreciation.